# How to check the external links in the nodes?

Tags: nodes, 9

I use on my Drupal 9 site, affiliate links for different products and services.

These links will appear in my nodes. The problem is that sometimes the provider changes its content, so sometimes the links return to a page not found or a page that does not match the product of the affiliate link.

How to check the external links in the nodes?

Is there a solution to check the validity of affiliate links (response code and page title).

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/linkchecker

Comment: @Kevin Thank you, does this module risk reducing the performance of the site?

Comment: I have no idea.